# Getting "TooManyRequests" error while calling "https://wse.ls.hereapi.com/2/findsequence.json". here-api

Tags: here-api

I am calling "**[https://wse.ls.hereapi.com/2/findsequence.json**"](https://wse.ls.hereapi.com/2/findsequence.json**%22) API to fetch destination sequence with 5-7 way points. Currently I am receiving "**TooManyRequests**" error. I checked in my account that only 45 requests has been made out of available **250k** per month transactions.

I would like to know the reason to receive such error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The waypoint sequence API has a restriction of 10 calls per day. If you have exceeded that, you will be able to make another call after 24 hours. Please take a look at some of the other restrictions on [point 8](https://developer.here.com/faqs#licensing--terms)

Comment: Is there any limit when we go for "Add-on" plan?